# Wrong database query locks

Tags: postgresql

We are troubleshooting our database issues, during that we came to know that it shows weird behavior that my query was blocked by other query which is not relevant to the table on which I am performing query.

In one table I am performing query like below:

```
UPDATE users
SET failedattempt = failedattempt + 1
WHERE userid =1
```

and my second query was

```
UPDATE resourcehistory
SET resourceid = 1
WHERE resourcehistoryid = 1
```

so I am confused why it shows locked? even if both do not have any common things or resources?

Comment: Is there a foreign key between the two tables? Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: you sure there is no trigger on users table which interacts with the resourcehistory table.........

Comment: In addition to that, there can be more than one statement in a transaction. Maybe an earlier statement in one of the transactions took the conflicting lock.

Comment: There is no trigger and there is no relationship between these two tables.

Comment: Postgresql 11.1 version we are using

Comment: Examine `pg_locks` and your code to figure out which transaction is holding which lock and which statements are responsible.